# ggplot - automatically adjust axis ranges so that they are the same

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for a way to automatically adjust axis ranges in ggplot so that the x axis and the y axis always have the same range.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Here we can see that the x-axis ranges from 10 to 35, and the y-axis from 1.5 to 5.5 (approximately).

If I wanted to do this manually, it would be easy:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  xlim(1.5, 35) + 
  ylim(1.5, 35)
```

[image]

However that is not really easy to do outside of this simplified example, so I would like to find a way to automatically make the axes ranges same.

Comment: `coord_fixed()` is the closest I know, but it's different from what you have requested.  Something similar here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/equal-scale-for-x-and-y-axis-in-a-ggplot-plot/136625

Comment: Since this (as with many things `ggplot2`) is determined at _render time_, even `coord_fixed(ratio=1)` (for preserving aspect-ratio) will produce undesirable results, since it preserves the ratio but not extending the short axis to fill the canvas. This type of extension is typically deferred for inclusion in `ggplot2`, where a better fit might be in one of the ggplot2-extension packages (e.g., `ggh4x`, `ggforce`, many more).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tidymodels::coord_obs_pred()](https://tune.tidymodels.org/reference/coord_obs_pred.html) is close to what you want, although it also sets the aspect ratio to 1 by default.  You can change it to a different value by specifying the `fixed` argument, but AFAICT you can't easily change it back to "free" (i.e., whatever the current shape of the graphics window suggests).

```r
library(tidymodels)
gg0 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) +  geom_point()
gg0 + coord_obs_pred()
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great. In my case it is actually beneficial that the aspect ratio is 1

Answer (score 2):

I actually do this fairly often when plotting scatterplots of paired data for better comparison, and what I do is to simply use the range of x and y as limits.

It's fully automated, no extra package is needed, and you're free to set the coordinate ratio with coord_ratio to your liking.

```r
library(ggplot2)

mylims <- range(with(mtcars, c(mpg, wt)))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = mylims, ylim = mylims)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>